# Python xgboost: some trees contain only a single leaf node (no splits)

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I fitted an extreme gradient boosting model using the `xgboost 0.6` package in `Python 3.6.3` (running on `macOS Sierra 10.12.6`). When I examined the dump of trees, I noticed that many of the trees do not contain any splits - they are just single leaf nodes:

```
params={'colsample_bylevel':0.25,'gamma':3,'learning_rate':0.2,'max_depth':2,'n_estimators':250,'reg_alpha':0.5,'reg_lambda':3,'subsample':0.5}
model = XGBClassifier(**params, seed=12345, nthread=1, silent=True)
model.fit(X, y) # X and y are numpy arrays (13 predictors and an outcome)

tree_dump = model.get_booster().get_dump()
tree_dump[0]
Out[765]: '0:leaf=-0.387394\n'
tree_dump[1]
Out[766]: '0:leaf=-0.322484\n'
tree_dump[2]
Out[767]: '0:leaf=-0.285089\n'
tree_dump[3]
Out[768]: '0:leaf=-0.26167\n'
tree_dump[4]
Out[769]: '0:leaf=-0.240752\n'
tree_dump[5]
Out[770]: '0:leaf=-0.226565\n'
tree_dump[6]
Out[771]: '0:[f0<6.28879] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:[f5<6.08075] yes=3,no=4,missing=3\n\t\t3:leaf=-0.21372\n\t\t4:leaf=0.00931895\n\t2:leaf=-0\n'
```

As you can see above, the first 6 trees are just leaves.

Is this behavior normal? If so, what is the point of having multiple single-leaf trees? Surely these could all be reduced to 1 single-left tree?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can now answer my own question... This behavior is to be expected given the hyperparameter values that I am using.

With 13 predictors and `colsample_bylevel` = 0.25, only 3 predictors are sampled per tree, and these may not be significant enough to result in a split. Setting `colsample_bylevel` = 1.0 increases the number of trees with splits, but there are still some that comprise only a single leaf node.

The parameters `gamma` and `min_child_weight` control the number of leaf nodes. Setting `colsample_bylevel` = 1.0, `gamma` = 0 and `min_child_weight` = 0, all but 1 of the 250 trees now contain splits.

Comment: Where did you come with those hyper parameters. . . They seem awful to me.

Comment: @EranMoshe I chose them by 10-fold cross validation. Why do you say they are awful?

Comment: 'colsample_bylevel':0.25 I would generally go with 0.75, but it depends on how many features you have. 'learning_rate':0.2 Maybe go lower like 0.1 or 0.05 and use more n_estimators and "early_stopping". About 'reg_alpha':0.5,'reg_lambda':3 I don't know a lot. I'm not tuning them in my models

Comment: @EranMoshe Thanks for the advice! I did try the hyperparameter values you suggest (higher column sampling, lower learning rates and more trees), but these are the values that did best based on cross-validated AUC.